# Can two 500 GB external hard drives be used like a single 1 TB hard drive to use for Time Machine?

Tags: mac, backup, time-machine

My new internal hard drive is 1 TB.

Comment: Sure! You may pool/union the 2 external drives (CoreStorage, RAID, MHDDFS, maybe ZFS) all with the downside of a higher probability of failure. But how is this related to your new internal 1 TB drive?

Comment: My TB hard drive will probably get filled before the end of the year.  I want to make sure I can back it all up to both 500 GB hard drives.

Comment: I would rather get a new 2-4 TB external drive to provide sufficient space to "breathe". 2 x 500 GB drives (probably at least 3 years old) have a somehow low [survival probability](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/226527/93229).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your system there are several methods to "concatenate" two or more external drives.

- RAID0: `diskutil createRAID stripe TMRAID JHFS+ disk1 disk2`
- JBOD: `diskutil createRAID concat TMRAID JHFS+ disk1 disk2`
- CoreStorage: `diskutil cs create disk1s2 disk2s2`. A CoreStorage Logical Volume has to be created addtionally.
- ZFS: This requires the additional installation of [software](https://openzfsonosx.org/wiki/Downloads). [Link](https://github.com/cmosetick/Mac-Hacks/blob/master/FileSystems/ZFS-TimeMachine-setup.md) to Time Machine setup.
- MHDDFS: This requires the additional installation of software. [~Setup link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/164630/93229) (I didn't test this solution as a Time Machine destination).

At the time of writing the new APFS (available in Sierra) apparently [doesn't support](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/FAQ/FAQ.html) Time Machine backups.

---

None of these solutions is recommended as Time Machine destination volume.

- The [survival probability](https://superuser.com/questions/65355/is-raid-0-as-risky-as-people-say-it-is) of the 500 GB drives (I assume they are at least 3 years old) is low compared to a new single drive.
- Since both drives are attached externally (via USB, FW etc.) the mechanical handling is error prone. If you detach any of the two drives accidentally while in use, you may loose the whole content because the volume usually is not recoverable afterwards.

I recommend to get a new single external drive (2 TB - 4 TB) which also provides some additional space to "breathe".